# Malloc library on shared memory

Tags: c, linux, malloc, shared-memory

I want to have a library containing all of the APIs in malloc family, including malloc, free, calloc, realloc and memalign on linux platform. All the functions should work on a shared memory area acquired from `shm_get` and `shm_at`. If not enough memory, the library could just return a `NULL` but not try to enlarge the space (shared memory can't do that). It shouldn't use syscalls like `brk` or `mmap` to get new memory. The library is for fast inter-process data communication.

I have investigated on Github and found some repositories.

- https://github.com/ChrisDodd/shm_malloc. This uses memory mapped file. For the performance reason, I want to use pure (shared) memory.
- https://github.com/ksuarz/shmalloc & https://github.com/dcshi/ncx_mempool. Both of them don't provide enough interfaces and are out of maintenance.

I'm wondering if there have been some reliable solutions to do malloc family operations on shared memory? This is a basic part of my whole project, I would rather use something existing there than modify the unmaintained repositories above myself.

By the way, I found there are allocator implementations in `Boost.Interprocess` to allocate c++ objects in shared memory. Can I wrap it to build a malloc API version? If so, how?

Comment: You can change my code to use POSIX shm pretty trivially (just change the two `open` calls to `shm_open`), but that is unlikely to be faster.  Changing it to use SYSV shared memory calls would be harder (and mostly pointless, as they're obsolete and any system that supports them will support something newer)

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow.